# Autopopulate fields on creation of new object in related list from related object?

Tags: javascript, page-layout, related-list, configuration

If I have Object A with related list of Objects B, when I make a new object B in this list, can I populate some fields automatically with data from related object A?

Comment: is my answer solved your purpose? I didn't hear back

Answer (score 1):

You need to do URLhacking.

So, find the respective parent field in the Child object's page layout and through javascript button, pass the value as URL parameter.

Here is an sample example of auto populating Account's field into Child Object's page layout when it is opened for related list (Custom button click).

You need to identify specific key like `CF00N1600000EhWcc=` doing `View Page source`.

This value is org specific, so before deploying this code of production, you have identify proper entry in production.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/apex.js")} 
var url2 = "/a1Q/e?"; 

document.location.href = '{!$Site.CurrentSiteUrl}'; 

var callingURL = document.location.href; 
var position = callingURL.lastIndexOf("/"); 
var recordId = callingURL.substring(position + 1,position + 1+ 15); 

if(recordId.length==15 && recordId.startsWith('001')) 
{ 
    var accountRec = sforce.connection.query("select Name from Account where Id='" + recordId + "'"); 
    var records1 = accountRec.getArray('records'); 
    if(records1 !=null) 
    { 
        var strURL = url2 + "&" + "CF00N1600000EhWcc=" + encodeURIComponent("{!$User.FirstName}" + " " + "{!$User.LastName}") 
        + "&" + "CF00N1600000EhWcD=" + encodeURIComponent(accountRec.records.Name) + "&" + "CF00N1600000EhWcD_lkid=" + recordId 
        + "&" + 'retURL=' + recordId; 
    }
} 

window.open(strURL, "_self");
```

Comment: Or you could just use a URL button and no need for all the JS

Comment: I check that then